# Is there an analytic form of the mode of a multivariate lognormal random variable?

Tags: lognormal-distribution, multivariate-analysis

Is there an analytic form of the mode of a multivariate log-normal random variable?

$Y$ is said to be a log-normal multivariate of dimension $d$ if $(ln Y_1,...,ln Y_d)$ is normal multivariate with law $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Write the probability density function (pdf) $f(Y_1,...,Y_d)$ of multivariate log-normal distribution with $d$ dimension.
2. Get logarithm of pdf $g(Y_1,...,Y_d) = log(f(Y_1,...,Y_d))$.
3. Derive the partial derivative of $g$: ${\partial g} \over {\partial Y_i}$, $i = 1,...,d$.
4. Let the partial derivatives be 0, and get the solution of $Y_i$, which is the mode.
5. The answer is $Y=exp(\mu-\Sigma 1_{d\times 1})$, where $1_{d\times 1} = [1,1,...,1]^T$ with length being $d$.